# Conditionally switch between layouts in Android

Tags: android

How do you switch between layouts in an activity and populate fields based on layout currently used?

For example if there is a logic in a view to load a view:

```
  if(category == 1){ 
      setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
  }else{
      setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
      title.setText("myTitle");

  }
```

If the else code is called the view never sets the title TextView to the String.

How do I accomplish conditionally going between the two views?

Comment: I'd go through two activitys rather than two views but need more information on your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to use [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). The advantage over the choices dimitris mentioned is that each fragment has it's own lifecycle, so you can delegate all code related to each view to its fragment, and keep your main activity clean.

To do this, simply use a FrameLayout in the Activity as a placeholder for the fragments. Fragments can communicate with the activity by using the listener pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to flip across difference `Views` you can examine various possibilities, such as:

- `ViewPager` via the compatibility library (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)
- `ViewFlipper` or `ViewSwitcher` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html)
- Or even a simple `FrameLayout` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Hope this helps for now! In case you need anything specific please shoot it!

Comment: Without knowing more context I think ViewSwitcher is great. I use it all the time and its super easy to add animations to.

Comment: "You can only call setContentView once!" That is wrong. You can call it more than once.

Comment: But in most cases, it's poor design to call `setContentView()` more than once.  It's usually better to use separate Fragments or Activities as others have suggested.  Using separate Fragments or Activities helps to isolate your code, so that classes only interact with a single layout.

Answer (score 0):

BTW have you considered Fragments. They are meant to deal with conditional layouts. Their basic motivation is screen sizes etc. But they can also fit your problem.

Refer to:

- [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)